# Functions are not being found

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I am new to C hence apologies for a simple question.

I am using code of [statistics library in C](http://freesourcecode.net/cprojects/97697/Statistics-library-in-c#.YzhabUhBzQU) with following commands:

```
gcc -Wall -I/usr/local/include -c statlib.c
```

It creates `statlib.o`. Similar for other files.

Current list of files are:

```
$ ls -ltrh
total 112K
-rw-r--r-- 1 auser auser 2.1K Oct  1 20:41  nprob.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 auser auser 1.5K Oct  1 20:42  regtest.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 auser auser  32K Oct  1 20:43  statlib.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 auser auser 7.4K Oct  1 20:43  statlib.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 auser auser 3.7K Oct  1 20:47  stattest.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 auser auser  33K Oct  1 20:51  statlib.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 auser auser 7.6K Oct  1 20:56  stattest.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 auser auser 3.9K Oct  1 21:00  regtest.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 auser auser 5.1K Oct  1 21:01  nprob.o
```

But when I use following command to create `stattest` executable, I get errors:

```
$ gcc  stattest.c 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cckj2CHi.o: in function `main':
stattest.c:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `sum'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `min_max'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x162): undefined reference to `range'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `a_mean'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x19c): undefined reference to `g_mean'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to `h_mean'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x1d6): undefined reference to `tukeys_trimean'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to `trimmed_mean'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x21c): undefined reference to `midrange'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x239): undefined reference to `median'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x25f): undefined reference to `percentile'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x27c): undefined reference to `quartiles'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x294): undefined reference to `interquartile_range'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x2b1): undefined reference to `mode'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x2ce): undefined reference to `svar'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x2ee): undefined reference to `pvar'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x30e): undefined reference to `rms'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x32e): undefined reference to `p_stdev'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x34e): undefined reference to `s_stdev'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x36e): undefined reference to `coeff_var'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x38e): undefined reference to `mean_dev'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x3ae): undefined reference to `std_err_mean'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x3ce): undefined reference to `skewness1'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x3ee): undefined reference to `skewness2'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x40e): undefined reference to `kurtosis1'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x42e): undefined reference to `kurtosis2'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x44e): undefined reference to `chi_square'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x46e): undefined reference to `confidence_95'
/usr/bin/ld: stattest.c:(.text+0x489): undefined reference to `confidence_99'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why can't I create a executable? Where is the problem but how can it be solved?

Comment: Assuming the functions are defined in `statlib.c`, you have to specify either the `.c` file or the `.o` file to the compiler/linker, e.g. something like `gcc -Wall -I/usr/local/include stattest.c statlib.c -o stattest` or `gcc stattest.c statlib.o -o stattest` or `gcc -c stattest.c` followed by `gcc  stattest.o statlib.o -o stattest`

Comment: Some functions like `log` and `sqrt` are not in `statlib.c`. They should be in `math.h`. Other functions in error are there in `statlib.c`

Comment: Then for math functions you probably need `-lm` (for the linkung step).

Comment: Yes, it works. You should enter this as an answer. Answers are read more than the comments.

Comment: And you should add all information to the question and preferably show the code in your question as a [mre]. The question doesn't show any reference to `log` or `sqrt` in the error messages or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of running:

```
gcc  stattest.c
```

run it with all the files you have already compiled:

```
gcc statlib.o stattest.o regtest.o nprob.o -o stattest
```

(the last `-o stattest` will name the output program as `stattest`, and not the default name used by the compiler --`a.out`)

Comment: Can I not put all c files (instead of o files) on the command line and get an executable file?

Comment: Yes, but that way, you will recompile them again, something you have already done.  The compilation goes faster if you just let the compiler call the linker and just link.  A bit confuse for a beginner.

Comment: When you have a program with hundreds of source files, and you change only one line in one file, it is normally faster (much much faster) to compile only the piece you have modified and go directly to the linking phase that doesn't require the computing effort of compilation.  Compiling a large program can take hours (or even days)

Comment: BTW, if you learn how to use `make` tool, you will get a program that computes which files have to be compiled, based on the modification timestamps each file has (if the source is newer than the compiled file, compilation is needed, if some of the `.o` files is newer than the final program, then linking phase is needed)